# Odoo13-CE: Module: sale.order: What inherit_id do I need to inherit quotation tree/list view?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

Module: sale.order: What inherit_id do I need to inherit quotation tree/list view (see the screenshot)?

I tried this  inherit_id ="sale.view_quotation_tree_with_onboarding", but it does not work.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply follow the steps after activating developer mode.

[image]
You can see the External ID: Which you need to use in 'inherit_id'.

[image]